# How to handle load balancer with api-gateway in microservices world?

Tags: node.js, microservices, api-gateway

In microservices there is api-gateway, which is entry point to all the services.

I think api-gateway is proxy to other microservices.

But how it's end up with load balancer? api-gateway is just a proxy which mean there is no "work" done in the api-gateway server.

So if my load balancer is point into api-gateway it mean nothing.

The load balancer getting the request and point it into api-gateway.

So load balancer is meanless thing in microservice world?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the load balancer if you have multiple instances that holds the api-gateway to point the requests to them in one load balancing methods.

For example the failover method. Assume that you have 2 instances holding api-gateway and the 1st is down for any reason, the load balancer will switch the requests automatically to the second.

It's very helpful technology that helps you to avoid down time in production mode.